# updating tableview after alamofire request completes

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

I get a json block from my server which I then proceed to process into my managed objects and upon completion my table view is reloaded to show the new content and this works ok apart from one small problem.

in the processing of the json I get a url for an image which I use an extension on UIImageView to get again using alamofire and this writes the downloaded image to disk.

The problem is the image is supposed to be displayed on the same table row for its managed object but what happens is the processing of the entire json completes and returns to the tableview before the save to disk has completed so the images do not come through.

how do I let the tableview know that each image is ready upon completed save so its related row can update?

extension UIImageView {

```
//
// downloads image from supplied url and writes to disk using supplied destination path
//
func imageFromUrl(urlString: String, destinationPath: String) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString).response { _, _, data, _ in

        // only if we go data
        if let data = data {

            // cast to jpg image
            let imageData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(data: data)!, 1)!)

            // and write to disk
            imageData.writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: true)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
func imageFromUrl(urlString: String, destinationPath: String,handleFinishLoad:()->()) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString).response { _, _, data, _ in

        // only if we go data
        if let data = data {

            // cast to jpg image
            let imageData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(data: data)!, 1)!)

            // and write to disk
            imageData.writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: true)
            handleFinishLoad()
        }
    }
}
```

and in tableviewcell:

```
    yourImageView.imageFromUrl(url, destinationPath: path) { () -> () in
        // downloadfinish 
        // update cell ...
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
//    in class A: DataService
//    i use static function to example. You should create a singleton for DataService and use func : singleton.getData....
    static func getData(handleComplete:(datas:NSArray)->()){ // get json data from server
        // data is array with every item is your object with contain urlimage, name... or it 's nsdictionary too
        Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString).response { _, _, data, _ in
            let arrayReturn = NSMutableArray()
            // parse data and add to a array or add every dictionary to array
            handleComplete(arrayReturn)
        }
    }

//    in class B:  yourViewController (this class contain your tableview)
//    in viewdidload
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.getData { (datas) -> () in
            // set data for tableview
            self.tableviewData = datas
            // numberofrow tableview is self.tableviewData.count
            // every cell of tableview have data is every item of self.tableviewData
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }

//    in  CellForRowAtIndexpath, create your cell- have uiimageview
//     and setimage for it
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // create cell
        cell.imageview.imageFromUrl(url, destinationPath: path) { () -> () in
            // downloadfinish
            // set image for cell.imageview
            // But it not good. You can use SDWebImage lib , set image 's url for uiimageview. it 's so easy
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising, but a slight problem...let me explain further..sorry..  The json loading is in one class and when it is done then it calls back to the other class and it is this second class that reloads the tableview and at that point it is getting the cell image from the saved destination path written to the managed object so the alamofire block does not know which cell it pertains to as all it does is download and save to disk...if that makes sense?

Comment: ok, i will not try explain to you because my english not good. But i code and you ... wait me

Comment: Thanks, will try your suggestion.  Can say I completely follow but will try and let you know.  Thanks, will be back soon with the results ;-)